# How prove this $a_{1}a_{2}...a_{k}\mid a_{N+1}a_{N+2}...a_{N+k}$

Tags: number-theory

**Question:**

> Find all Arithmetic progressions $a_{1},a_{2},...$ of natural numbers for which there exists natural number $N>1$ such that for every $k\in \mathbb{N}$:
>
> $$a_{1}a_{2}...a_{k}\mid a_{N+1}a_{N+2}...a_{N+k}$$

This problem is from Iran TST 2013:can see :
http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=3032829&sid=feebf5330bd4d5da7eabb8729f2f7e71#p3032829

and this proble answer is $a_{n}=nd$,and this links $Sco0orpiOn$ methods? is true?

**His solution:**

> let $ K>N $ and let $ t=a_{1}a_{2}...a_{N} $ and let $ a_{i}=ia+b $ where $ \gcd(a,b)=1$ (we can take out the greatest common divisor w.l.o.g)
>   then we have  $ t\mid a_{k+1}a_{k+2}...a_{N+k}  $ for every natural $K>N$ so if $$a>0
>  t\mid ((k+1)a+b)((k+2)a+b)...((N+k)a+b) , \gcd(a_{i},a)=1 \Rightarrow \gcd(t,a)=1 \Rightarrow  \exists c $$: $ ac  \equiv 1 \pmod{t} $
>   $$ ((k+1)+bc)((k+2)+bc)...((N+k)+bc)a^N \equiv ((k+1)a+b)((k+2)a+b)...((N+k)a+b) \pmod{t}  $$
>   now put $k=st-bc $ for a big $s$ then $ ((k+1)+bc)((k+2)+bc)...((N+k)+bc)a^N \equiv N!a^N \equiv 0 \pmod{t} $
>    $ t \mid N!a^N \Rightarrow  N!a^N \leq t \leq N!a^N \Rightarrow b=0 $

My Question: He solution is true? and Have other methods? Thank you

Comment: why close? Thank you,I think this is good problem.

Comment: What are you asking for exactly ? You gave both the problem and its solution.

Comment: No point putting a bounty on a question if you are going to ignore comments on it. Please engage with the comment @Ewan left some months ago.